# Linking Custom Fields to Database Records

Tags: custom-field, database, users

Hey there im fairly new to wordpress and php, but have a strong programming/database background.

I recently learned about custom fields and am wondering if it is at all possible to do the following with them in conjunction with database tables...

I want to be able to display a picture and name value for the person who posted the 'static' home page message. I would like to reference these values from a custom field bt have it linked to a pre-existing table of users. I say 'static' because its nt really a blog post and would be changed maybe once or twice a year.

Is this the correct approach to this idea or does wordpress offer a more elegant approach?

Thank you for your response/s in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Custom field data saved in the wp_postmeta table. Best way to access custom field is using wordpress built-in functions.

for example:

```
<?php
 $mykey_values = get_post_custom_values('my_key');
 foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) {
     echo "$key  => $value ('my_key')<br />";
 }
?>
```

0 => First value ('my_key')

1 => Second value ('my_key')

2 => Third value ('my_key')

You will get more information about accessing custom field in this link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

you also folllow further on

```
http://wpshout.com/everything-wordpress-custom-fields/
```

Comment: Interesting thanks for the reply. What about accessing the avatar image used by the user get_avatar() would that also work